# What methods of time travel exist in the World of Darkness?

Tags: world-of-darkness, time-travel

I know mages can do it with their respective sphere, and vampires with a high level of Temporis.

Are there more ways of time traveling in WoD?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To my knowledge, there are only three ways to *travel through time* in the classic WoD:

- Forward at a rate of one second per second as anything else. That's nothing special, as that is what all the universe does.

  - Special relativity applies, so you could slower in with \$\frac {1\text{ s}}{\gamma\text{ s}}<1\frac{\text{s}}{\text{s}}\$ in relation to the non-moving world, if you travel fast enough by mundane means, as \$\gamma={\sqrt{1-{\frac{v²}{c²}}}}\$ with [\$v\$ your speed and \$c\$ the speed of light in a vacuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_speed). Those speeds need a lot of energy, very long acceleration or Magic - and are far beyond what Swara or vamps with celerity 10 can muster. But (thanks to the Technocracy) relativity applies. Ok, enough physics.
- Use of the Time sphere as a real Mage (and getting clobbered by Paradox in the process).

  - And of course use of an artifact that uses time
- Use of the Temporis Disciplin as an ancient Brujah.

Within some broad borders, there are two ways for Fera and other shifters to *experience past times*:

- Visiting an umbral realm, most notably a Wolfhome or the Battleground, allows to experience a past time that gone by, but you don't actually travel back in time.

  - This also is open to Spirit mages even.
- Using Mnesis, a Mokolé can experience and relive the past, though again it is more experiencing it not changing it by being there.

There is one fringe case that could be seen as *time manipulation*:

- Level 5 Nomenclature as a Mummy allows to erase somebody from history. They never have existed after you used the rite. Only you remember them.

Comment: *"... and get clobbered by Paradox in the process."*  This, absolutely this.  The description from... Horizon?  (Whichever one, back in the '90s, had the level six sphere descriptions.)  The description  of the Paradox dangers of time travel were **brutal**.

Comment: @Ghotir, the Paradox only hits if you try to go **back** in time.  Going forward is allowed.  You just cease existing in that spot for a set amount of time.  There's some Paradox but you can minimize it.

Comment: @ShadoCat Correct: it was going *back* in time that was brutal (even just to "remember" your keys on a coffee table).  I could have specified.